# consistency of EM estimation in Kalman filter

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, signal-processing, time-series, kalman-filter

I do not understand the properties of EM algorithm of Kalman.

Assume one has a state-space model:
$$
z_{t} = B x_{t} + v_{k}\\
x_{t+1} = A x_{t} + w_{k},
$$
where noise terms are i.i.d. such that $v_{k} \sim N(0, Q)$ and $w_{k} \sim N(0, R)$. Assume that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are known.

The question: does EM algorithm provide a consistent estimation of $Q$ and $R$, the observation and transition covariances?

My discovery:

According to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198246/em-algorithm-with-pykalman/58560992#58560992

and some simple simulations, the estimate of the covariance matrix is far from the true values.

From the discussion here:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24417/em-algorithm-and-kalman-filter

> However, EM algorithm has a drawback. It only gives suboptimal solution. In other words, the parameters estimated by EM algorithm are only local minimum/maximum, rather than global minimum/maximum. Therefore, further turning may be needed.

Therefore, my conclusion is that in general Kalman EM does not provide a consistent estimator of the variance.